# Почему data появляется на секунду и исчезает jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery

Why????? На всякий случай код

```
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
    var name = $("#form_name").val();
    var email = $("#form_email").val();
    var text = $("#msg_text").val();
    var dataString = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        text: text
    }


$.post( "example.php", dataString, function () {
    console.log('ggggg')
})


});
```

example.php

```
echo 'raz dva tri 4etyre pyat';?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что отправка формы (и последующая перезагрузка страницы) по нажатию `submit` кнопки `#myBtn` идет своим ходом.

```
$("#myBtn").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```

Comment: Спасибо Спасибо Спасибо Спасибо

Comment: @LyubaIvanova На здоровье. Успехов!